# Issue running a shell script in python using subprocess

Tags: python, shell

I want to run a shell script from python.

The shell script is something which runs a server, which needs ctrl+c to break.

How to do that is there a way to run such type of scripts from python.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking about actually running the server, or are you asking about how to transfer the `ctrl+c` to the server from within the python wrapper?

Comment: Remember that `ctrl+c` simply sends the process a SIGINT signal - this can be done in other ways - you don't actually have to hit those keys on a keyboard

Comment: i want to run the server and python shouldn’t wait for that @Lix

Comment: You need to run it in the background by adding an ampersand `&` after its name.

Answer (score 0):

Just send the `SIGINT` signal to your app:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
# When it needs to be stopped
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

Comment: let's say if server.sh starts a server, how can you write that in the above code

Comment: Give more details then. In the original question you said you need to kill the app which can be killed only by hiting ctrl+c. The code above does that. But when should you do that is another question which I assumed you have the answer for.

Comment: I need to run a script which runs a server. python program should trigger that and should proceed without waiting or blocking